# linkedin hiding/editing short URL

Tags: url, share, linkedin-api

I was looking through different forums, but didn't find anything related to my small issue...
[Clickable title](http://www.google.md/#hl=mo&source=hp&q=asd&btnG=C%C4%83utare+Google&gbv=2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=570d93e0f8e456a7&biw=1920&bih=837) google.com

And the google.com is gonna be of small font and gray color. 
Is it possible somehow to hide/edit/ask LinkedIn not to show that small gray formatted domain of the submitted link? It's pretty crucial for my project, and any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using the LinkedIn API (nor using the website).  The only thing I could think of would be to use your own URL shortener and share that link instead.